# Excel: Alternative to CEILING for rounding to nearest value

Tags: excel, windows-phone-7, excel-formula, ceil

Normally I ask about work stuff so here's something different. To approach my new year's resolution in the nerdiest way possible, I'm creating a gym program in an excel file. I'll be doing ramped sets, which means each set I increase the weight be 10%. The formula I'm using allows a base weight (e.g. last week's max) to be entered, and calculates all the previous sets, rounded, up or down, to the nearest 2.5kg (1.25kg plates on each side of a bar; the smallest increment available).

```
=CEILING(($B13 - ($A$2 * 0.1)) - 1.25, 1.25 * 2)
```

In this formula, B13 is the next set after this one, and A2 is the base weight. So each set is 10% of the base weight less than the set after it, rounded to the nearest 2.5kg by the CEILING function.

Here's the kicker: the device I'll be taking with me is a Windows Phone 7 (I know, I know!). Its Excel program apparently doesn't support the CEILING function (or FLOOR). Is there a way to achieve this using the supported formulas, which according to MS Support are:

> ABS, ACOS, AND, ASIN, ATAN, ATAN2, AVERAGE, CHOOSE, COLUMNS, CONCATENATE, COS, COUNT, COUNTA, COUNTBLANK, COUNTIF, DATE, DATEVALUE, DAVERAGE, DAY, DCOUNT, DCOUNTA, DDB, DEGREES, DGET, DMAX, DMIN, DPRODUCT, DSTDEV, DSTDEVP, DSUM, DVAR, DVARP, ERROR.TYPE, EXACT, EXP, FACT, FIND, FV, HLOOKUP, HOUR, IF, INDEX, INT, IRR, ISBLANK, ISERR, ISERROR, ISLOGICAL, ISNA, ISNONTEXT, ISNUMBER, ISTEXT, LEFT, LEN, LN, LOG, LOG10, LOOKUP, LOWER, MATCH, MAX, MID, MIN, MINUTE, MOD, MONTH, N, NA, NOT, NOW, NPER, NPV, OR, PI, PMT, POWER, PRODUCT, PROPER, PV, RADIANS, RAND, RANK, RATE, REPLACE, REPT, RIGHT, ROUND, ROWS, SECOND, SIN, SLN, SQRT, STDEV, STDEVP, SUBSTITUTE, SUM, SUMIF, SUMPRODUCT, SYD, T, TAN, TIME, TIMEVALUE, TODAY, TRIM, TRUNC, UPPER, VALUE, VAR, VARP, VLOOKUP, YEAR, FALSE, and TRUE.

And for those of you who were wondering, no, I swear I'm not as lonely as I must sound.

Comment: Google spreadsheets support the CEILING function.  My workout spreadsheet isn't as complicated as yourn but that's what I use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work with the ROUND function, no? Just divide your value by 2.5, round it to the nearest integer and multiply it again by 2.5

Comment: Works a treat, pfnuesel, thanks. Apparently I'm already a bit of a musclehead.

Comment: So what's the replacement formula, then? I assume =ROUND(($B13 - ($A$2 * 0.1))/2.5,0)*2.5 - Note that won't give you the same result as your original formula with CEILING if $B13 - ($A$2*0.1) is a multiple of 1.25 that isn't a multiple of 2.5, e.g. 23.5

Comment: Yep, that's the formula barry. That error shouldn't be an issue for my purpose, since i'd always use multiples of 2.5. Otherwise I'd build myself up lopsided, having 1.25 more on one side of the bar than the other :)